# Controller parent sharing content between its child

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a base class which has some properties. I'm inheriting this class into two other controllers. Whenever I set a content to this variable, though, the content is shared between the two controllers. I don't this to happen, otherwise I'd have used Mixins. I want to set the content in one child to something and when I go to the other route, the content is still blank.

```
// base controller
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    method: null,
    actions: {
        changeMethod() {
            this.set('method', 'content is shared');
        }
    }
}
// children.js
import BaseClass from './base-class';

export default BaseClass.extend({ //code here });

// child1.hbs
{{method}} - it shows the same as child2.hbs

// child2.hbs
{{method}} - it shows the same as child1.hbs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what I had to do is the same as they recommend for Mixins: I've created a `init()` method setting the variables to the default value. In the example I gave it became:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    method: null,
    init() {
        this._super():
        this.set('method', null);
    },
    actions: {
        changeMethod() {
            this.set('method', 'content is shared');
        }
    }
}
```

The objects created share the same prototype. According to Mozilla:

> Changes to the Object prototype object are seen by all objects through prototype chaining, unless the properties and methods subject to those changes are overridden further along the prototype chain.  This provides a very powerful although potentially dangerous mechanism to override or extend object behavior.

More into this topic can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

There are two ways to avoid the sharing behavior.

1. Use computed properties
2. Initializing on the `init` function, as I did

More reference in the subject [here](https://dockyard.com/blog/2014/04/17/ember-object-self-troll) as @lock said

Comment: If you are subclassing framework class and you override init` method make sure you call `this._super(...arguments)!` If you don't, a parent class may not have an opportunity to do important setup work, and you'll see strange behavior in your application.[Reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_initializing-instances)

Comment: Hi Marcus, this behaviour is due to how JavaScript prototype inheritance works, not Controllers being singletons. See https://dockyard.com/blog/2014/04/17/ember-object-self-troll for another example.